# How do I make my game slower (slower FPS)?

Tags: java, timer

So I wrote this code for a game and now that game is very speeded up. I want to lower the FPS so that the game slows down a bit.

I thought the only way out for me is to make a timer. But I'm finding it difficult to locate where to place the timer? Can anyone help me with this?

So I wrote this code for a game and now that game is very speeded up. I want to lower the FPS so that the game slows down a bit.

I thought the only way out for me is to make a timer. But I'm finding it difficult to locate where to place the timer? Can anyone help me with this?

```
public class Gamepanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 500;

    private Thread thread;

    private boolean running;

    private boolean right = false, left = false, up = false, down= false;

    private BodyPart b;
    private ArrayList<BodyPart> snake;

    private Apple apple;
    private ArrayList<Apple> apples;

    private Random r;

    private int xCoor = 10, yCoor = 10, size = 1;
    private int ticks = 0;


    public Gamepanel(){
        setFocusable(true);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        addKeyListener(this);

        snake = new ArrayList<BodyPart>();
        apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();

        r = new Random();

        start();

    }

    public void start () {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }


    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void tick() {


        if(snake.size()==0) {
            b= new BodyPart(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
            snake.add(b);
        }
        ticks++;
        if(ticks > 250000) {

            if(right) xCoor++;
            if(left) xCoor--;
            if(up) yCoor--;
            if(down) yCoor++;

            ticks = 0;

            b = new BodyPart(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
            snake.add(b);

            if(snake.size() > size) {
                snake.remove(0);
            }
        }
        if(apples.size()==0) {
            int xCoor = r.nextInt(49);
            int yCoor = r.nextInt(49);

            apple = new Apple(xCoor,yCoor,10);
            apples.add(apple);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < apples.size(); i++) {
            if(xCoor == apples.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor == apples.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                size++;
                apples.remove(i);
                i++;

            }
        }

        //COLLISION ON SNAKE BODY
        for (int i = 0; i < snake.size(); i++) {
            if(xCoor == snake.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor == snake.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                if(i != snake.size() - 1) {
                    System.out.print("Game Over");
                    stop();
                }

        }

        //COLLISION ON BORDER
        if(xCoor < 0 || xCoor > 49 || yCoor < 0 || yCoor > 49) {
            System.out.print("Game Over" + '\n');
            System.out.println("Your Score is: " + snake.size());
            stop();
        }
        }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        for (int i=0; i< WIDTH/10; i++) {
            g.drawLine(i * 10, 0, i * 10, HEIGHT);
        }
        for (int i=0; i< HEIGHT/10; i++) {
            g.drawLine(0, i * 10, HEIGHT, i * 10);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i< snake.size(); i++) {
            snake.get(i).draw(g);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i< apples.size(); i++) {
            apples.get(i).draw(g);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(running) {

            tick();
            repaint();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D && !left) {
            right = true;
            up = false;
            down=false;

        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A && !right) {
            left = true;
            up = false;
            down = false;

        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W && !down) {
            up=true;
            left=false;
            right=false;

        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S && !up) {
            down=true;
            left=false;
            right=false;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }


}
```

Comment: The proper solution would be to decouple the logic from the framerate...

Comment: Frame rate should never control game speed. Redesign your logic.

Comment: Your example is incomplete, thus __not reproducible__ (missing Apple, BodyPart, main). Have a look at this [Github-repo](https://github.com/Ajron96/SnakeGame) for timer placement, delay as well as start/stop conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that now, game speed won't be the same on different machines, as some computers may execute your code faster and some may execute slower.

If you want your game to execute on every computer with the same speed you need define some kind of speed for your snake (unit per second) and then in game loop update your snake position based on how much time elapsed from last frame (last call of tick method)

```
// snake speed
double speed = 1.0; // units per second

// in game loop (your tick method)
position = speed * deltaTime;
```

now your position is not anymore depended on game framerate. On faster devices game will update snake position more often but `deltaTime` will be smaller as well as changes of `position`, on the other hand on slower devices tick method will be called less frequent but `deltaTime` will be higher